# Python-Django: module import syntax conflicting

Tags: python, django, python-import

I hope this is not a duplicate, I couldn't find any other answer.

Going straight to the point, my problem is as follows.

I have a project in Django where django-apps use external custom modules.
This is the structure:

```
Project_dir/
  - core/
    - module_1.py
    - module_2.py
  - django_project/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - django_app_A/
    - views.py
  - manage.py
```

The problem is that I need to import some classes and methods of moudule_2 in module_1, and I would do so by simply, in module_1,

```
from module_2 import foo
```

When I run module_1 for testing, everything works fine. Nonetheless, I need to import module_1 in django_app_A/views.py, and I would do so by

```
from core.module_1 import Bar
```

Here's the problem: if I have another relative import in module_1, as I have, I will get a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_2'
```

UNLESS I use in module_1 the syntax

```
from .module_2 import foo
```

By doing so, the Django app will work fine and page will properly load, but at the same time I "break" the module_1, as I won't be able to run it stand-alone anymore, as I will get a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.module_2'
```

I have no idea how to fix this conflict and make both import syntax work at the same time.
Any clues? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use absolute imports as much as you can.

```
from core.module_2 import foo
```

Comment: I tried refeactoring all the scripts as you suggested, but didn't work. More specifically, it worked from within the django app but didn't when running stand-alone

Comment: How are you "running stand-alone"? There's all kinds of setup needed when running a Django module outside of Django itself.

Comment: What I need to run stand-alone is not a django module, but a custom one. I simply type python -i module_1 while in its directory

Comment: Why do you need to run it from that directory? Do it from the project root via `python -m core.module_2`.

Comment: Okay, now the error changed. I got: AttributeError: module 'core.module_1' has no attribute '__path__'

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but it sounds like a circular import problem to me.

Do you need the import to be on the "main" level? If you import module 2 inside of a class or function, simply write

```
def function_in_question():
    import module_1
    return module_1.whatever()
```

Another thing to look for: are you using it in a way that is actually circular? A function in module_2 using a function in module_1 that uses the function in module_2?

Comment: First there was a circular import problem (even though the function was imported but unused) but I fixed it, and the problem remains.
Edit: clicked by mistake.
I tried what you suggested but it didn't work... as soon as the function_in_question() runs and imports I get the same Exception

Comment: The other guy was more right than I was, I hate to say.

If this is a django app, the apps assume they can be accessed by their module names. So, for inter-app referencing you always want to use module names.

But, I would try one more very simple thing: leave your reference as `from module_2 import foo`, and add an `__init__.py` file to the `core` directory.

I see that you have got it down to the "no path" error, the init file might fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that was the very first thing I tried. In the end I am using a brutal work-around with a try-except around the imports I need... ugly, I know, but for now I can't think of anything else